# Hardening WMI: Any security beneifit to "winmgmt /standalonehost"?

Tags: hardening, wmi, standalonehost

Any security benefit to winmgmt operating outside of shared svchost processes via the command

`winmgmt /standalonehost` ?

As for security, yes, it is useful for changing wbem Authentication levels, which is changed by the command `winmgmt /standalonehost [#]` but does setting winmgmt as a standalone host have any security benefit on its own, ex `winmgmt /standalonehost`? For example, does a standalone host mitigate against attacks upon shared processes in svchost?

Another example. Group policy Svchost.exe mitigations add ACG-CIG exploit-protection enforcement and other process mitigation code integrity policies to svchost procsses. My question is does running WMI as a standalone or shared host result in any security impact with this policy enabled?

Just for reference, I will include **Webm Authentication levels**

```
WbemAuthenticationLevelDefault
0
    Moniker: Default
WMI uses the default Windows authentication setting. This is the recommended setting that allows WMI to negotiate to the level required by the server returning data. However, if the namespace requires encryption, use WbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy.
WbemAuthenticationLevelNone
1
    Moniker: None
Uses no authentication.
WbemAuthenticationLevelConnect
2
    Moniker: Connect
Authenticates the credentials of the client only when the client establishes a relationship with the server.
WbemAuthenticationLevelCall
3
    Call
Authenticates only at the beginning of each call when the server receives the request.
WbemAuthenticationLevelPkt
4
    Moniker: Pkt
Authenticates that all data received is from the expected client.
WbemAuthenticationLevelPktIntegrity
5
    Moniker: PktIntegrity
Authenticates and verifies that none of the data transferred between client and server has been modified.
WbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy
6
    Moniker: PktPrivacy
Authenticates all previous impersonation levels and encrypts the argument value of each remote procedure call. Use this setting if the namespace to which you are connecting requires an encrypted connection.
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of your question [Hardening WMI: Any security benefit to changing Impersonation level?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234675/hardening-wmi-any-security-benefit-to-changing-impersonation-level). Please delete it.

Comment: Good point. I'd be happy to work with competent mods and ask questions on websites that actually demonstrate genuine courtesy and respect to their userbase, I will ask elsewhere, you have yet to retract your false statements, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Tyler - this post is so similar to the existing one that it is for all intents and purposes a duplicate so closed as such. Also, I would ask you to pay attention to our code of conduct - your behaviour towards mentallurg, who is not a mod here, is not acceptable.

Comment: @Rory Alsop you are incorrect, they are very different questions. I have asked multiple questions within a single framework previously and have been told by moderators to create a separate question, so I followed the guidance I had previously been given by moderators who all to often keep changing the goal posts. I would ask you to pay attention and stick to the conduct and rules you attest and not engage in unacceptable behavior or cry victim when someone points out facts. It is unwelcome and people cannot grow or changed if incompetence is left unchallenged.

Comment: Answers to the dupe will answer this one - I cannot see anything to say these are different questions. Please articulate the differences. Also, and more importantly - the current issue I am pointing out to you is behavioural. Yours is the behaviour we would class as unacceptable. mentallurg was polite with you, and you were rude back. Do not do that - it is unacceptable here.